# Zxing scan stops

Tags: java, android, android-camera, android-alertdialog, zxing

Im using Zxing for scanning Qr-codes and https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog for some pretty dialogs. I check if i have internet connection when i launch the app and each time when i do a scan. My problem is that the scanner stops after 1st scan , it shows dialog popup , i press ok button and stops the scanning process , but camera is still showing. Do i have any mistakes in my code or logic ???

It doesnt enter second time in handleResult

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
    private SweetAlertDialog pDialog;
    private ZXingScannerView mScannerView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);   // Programmatically initialize the scanner view
        setContentView(mScannerView);                // Set the scanner view as the content view
        pDialog = new SweetAlertDialog(this, SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE);

        if (!Utils.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
            alertBadNetworkConnection("Network connection error", "Please check your internet connection");
        }
    }

    private void alertBadNetworkConnection(String title, String context) {
        pDialog.changeAlertType(SweetAlertDialog.ERROR_TYPE);
        pDialog.setTitleText(title)
                .setContentText(context)
                .setConfirmText("OK")
                .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        mScannerView.startCamera();
                    }
                })

                .show()
        ;
    }

    private void alertSuccess(String title, String context) {
        pDialog.changeAlertType(SweetAlertDialog.SUCCESS_TYPE);
        pDialog.setTitleText(title)
                .setContentText(context)
                .setConfirmText("OK")
                .setConfirmClickListener(new SweetAlertDialog.OnSweetClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(SweetAlertDialog sweetAlertDialog) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        mScannerView.startCamera();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this); // Register ourselves as a handler for scan results.
        mScannerView.startCamera();          // Start camera on resume
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();           // Stop camera on pause
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {

        if (!Utils.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
            alertBadNetworkConnection("Network connection error", "Please check your internet connection");
        } else {
            alertSuccess("Good job!", result.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the method that checks internet connection

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
                = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

Comment: Have you get any solution

Answer (score 0):

DO the following in your `handleResult()` method

```
    // If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
    mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
```

Example :

```
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {

    if (!Utils.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this)) {
        alertBadNetworkConnection("Network connection error", "Please check your internet connection");
    } else {
        alertSuccess("Good job!", result.getText());
       // If you would like to resume scanning, call this method below:
       mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }
}
```